# (Matlab) Symbolic Toolbox: (Empty Sym) error in function file

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have had the opportunity to obtain the following code as answer to my earlier question.

```
function [] = calc_third(varname_1, var_value_1, varname_2, var_value_2)

    gamma = sym('gamma');
    M1 = sym('M1');
    TR = sym('TR');

    eq = TR ==(((gamma - 1)*M1^2 + 2)*(2*gamma*M1^2 - gamma + 1))/(M1^2*(gamma + 1)^2);

    subs_eq = (subs(eq,[sym(varname_1), sym(varname_2)],[var_value_1,var_value_2]));

    missing_var = symvar(subs_eq)

    solve(subs_eq,missing_var)

end
```

It is supposed to give an output below in console:

```
>>calc_third('gamma', 0.5, 'TR', 100)

missing_var =

M1

ans =

(2*2^(1/2))/(3*88609^(1/2) + 893)^(1/2)
```

Instead, Matlab gives me the following error:

```
>> calc_third('gamma',1.4,'TR',100)

missing_var = 

   Empty cell array: 0-by-1

Warning: List of equations is empty. 
> In solve at 70
  In calc_third at 13

ans =

[ empty sym ]
```

I am on Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a), with symbolic toolbox.Have I miss anything out?

Comment: This works for me on Symbolic Math Toolbox Version 6.2 in MATLAB R2015a. It seems like in that old version, [symvar](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) cannot identify the remaining symbolic variable.

Comment: Also works for me on R2013a with the Symbolic Math Toolbox version 5.10

Comment: Have you checked that `subs` is even returning the correct result? It looks like you may be trying to use the newer array syntax to substitute multiple variables (in older versions this looks for and substitutes actual symbolic arrays). You need to use a cell array. *Don't look at the online documentation unless you're using the current `version` of Matlab* – instead use `doc` or `help` or the [archived documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html). Also `gamma` is the name of a commonly-used numeric and symbolic function. Have you tried changing the name of that variable?

Comment: @horchler It seems that even changing the `gamma` is not working, at least in the older version. And I have no way of validating the results because I have no access to newer Matlab. The results should contain only real and positive value, given the inputs are positive and real.

Comment: @Jethro: there's no need to "validate the results in a newer version." You should print out the output from the `subs` line in your code and check that it's actually performing the substitution as expected. If that's not working, it may not matter what `symvar` does. That's what the first part of my comment is about.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments from other users, looks like symvar cannot identify the remaining variables in R2011a. This is not an issue for newer Matlab, at least from R2013a, with symbolic math toolbox v5.10 onwards.